# ¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos

Tags: soporte, faq, formato

¿Qué son los magic-links? ¿Cómo funcionan?

What are magic-links? How do they work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For English, check the [original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/209901) on magic-links.

---

En [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/209901) se detallan los magic-links que pueden utilizarse en los comentarios para los enlaces más comunes.

Paso a detallar los disponibles actualmente:

- `[meta]` – enlace a Meta; el texto del enlace es el nombre del sitio. No hace nada si ya se está en Meta.
- `[main]` – igual que [meta], pero al revés.
- `[edit]` – enlace a la página para editar la publicación donde está este comentario. El texto del enlace es "edit", respetando la capitalización dada.
- `[help]` se explica solo. Este y los siguientes subapartados tienen siempre el texto "help center":

  - `[meta-help]` enlaza a "What is meta?" (/help/whats-meta)
  - `[help/on-topic]` enlaza a "What topics can I ask about here? (/help/on-topic)
  - `[help/dont-ask]` enlaza a "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" (/help/dont-ask)
  - `[help/behavior]` enlaza a "What kind of behavior is expected of users?" (/help/behavior).
- `[tour]` y `[meta-tour]` – equivalentes a la versión FAQ, pero enlaza al Tour de la página (resp. el Tour de la página Meta). El texto del enlace es "tour" (respetando las mayúsculas y minúsculas). También son válidas `[about]` y `[meta-about]`.
- `[ask]`, `[answer]` – enlaza a "How to Ask" / "How to Answer".
- `[so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`/`[meta.se]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – enlace a las páginas ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), el [Stack Exchange portal](http://stackexchange.com/)). El texto del enlace es el nombre del sitio.
- `[something.se]` – enlaza a something.stackexchange.com, si dicho sitio existe. El texto del enlace es el nombre del sitio. Usa `[ubuntu.se]` para Ask Ubuntu. `[meta.something.se]` enlaza al sitio meta.
- `[chat]` – enlaza al chat del sitio actual http://chat.stackexchange.com/, donde se muestra una lista de las salas activas del sitio. El texto del enlace es "{nombre del sitio} Chat".
- `[tag:tag-name]` como por ejemplo `[tag:traducción]` crea un enlace a dicha etiqueta, como [traducción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traducci%c3%b3n). También funciona en los comentarios.

Aparte de `[chat]` y `[edit]`, y además de `[chat-faq]`, todo funciona en el chat.

---

De esta forma, si vemos que un nuevo usuario necesita ayuda con el formato y la forma de escribir una pregunta aquí, podemos decir:

> Hola y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a `[edit](/edit)` para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: `[¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic)`. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Que se imprimirá así:

> Hola y bienvenido a [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/). Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/XXX/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tour) y leer [How to Ask](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).