# ¿Queremos una dirección tipo s.tk/spanish para que dirija a este sitio?

Tags: discusión

Hace unos días descubrí que Stack Exchange posee el dominio [s.tk](http://www.s.tk) ([What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109795/209901)) y lo usa para crear redirecciones a sitios de la red.

Por ejemplo, `s.tk/so` redirige a Stack Overflow. Propuse en Stack Overflow en español que se incluyera ese sitio en la lista ([¿Podemos tener la dirección s.tk/esso o s.tk/soes para que dirija a Stack Overflow en español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1771/83)) y rápidamente se ha conseguido: [`s.tk/soes`](http://s.tk/soes) redirige a http://es.stackoverflow.com.

Por ello, me pregunto: ¿solicitamos algo así como `s.tk/spanish` para este sitio?

<sub>Nota para mí mismo: [formulario para pedirlo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk/109802#comment911342_109802)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

## ¡Sí, sí, lo queremos!

Creo que es útil y lo explico en los comentarios...

---

Respuesta ganadora, por lo que lo he...

## ¡SOLICITADO!

Comment: **Razón 1:** It's free! **Razón 2:** Why not? **Razón 3:** Ahorrar caracteres en enlaces puestos en Twitter, que aquí uno intenta hacer promoción del sitio (de vez en cuando). Eso sí, yo lo intentaba pedir aún más corto: `s.tk/es` o `s.tk/sl` o algo así. **Razón 4:** _French Language_ lo tiene, ¿vamos a ser menos que ellos?

Comment: You soy de los que lo quiere aunque no sepa cómo lo voy a usar. Suelo usar los [magic links](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2497/5481) para enlazar a [something.se] en los comentarios, pero para enlaces en sitois externos creo que sería bueno tener una URL corta y fácil de recordar.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo lo de `s.tk/es` también es una idea. No sé si nos lo concederían, pues parecería que es la versión de `s.tk` (esto es, de [se]) en español. Lo intentamos y a ver qué nos conceden :) Añado otra razón: cuando uno está en un ordenador no propio, entrar en el sitio tecleando `spanish.stack...` es un poco paliza; con una dirección tan corta será mucho más ágil y fácil.

Comment: @fedorqui por eso decía lo de `/sl`, por Spanish Language...

Answer (score -1):

## No, no hace falta.

Me parece una gilipollez y así lo razono en los comentarios...