# Lista de comentarios útiles para el sitio

Tags: discusión, comentarios

A continuación detallo algunos comentarios tipo que pueden ser útiles.

Recurso útil relacionado: [¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2497/1674) por el cual por ejemplo tenemos que:

- `[tour]` enlaza al [Tour](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tour).
- `[edit]` enlaza a la edición de la publicación donde se escribe.
- `[ask]` enlaza a [How to ask](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).
- `[answer]` enlaza a [How to answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Esta página es Community Wiki.  ¡Todos a aportar!

Resumen de respuestas:

- [Usuario nuevo o despistado, muchos votos negativos sin comentario explicatoria](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2624/1674)
- [Usuario nuevo que no contesta a lo que se pregunta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2623/1674)
- [Una publicación es más un comentario que una respuesta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2627/1674)
- [Usuario nuevo que no pregunta correctamente](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2722/1674)
- [Un post es demasiado parecido a uno ya existente](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2651/1674)
- [Respuesta de un usuario nuevo, que aporta una hipótesis nueva sin aportar referencias](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2721/1674)
- [Vanilla introduction for new users](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3009/1674)
- [Un usuario plantea una nueva pregunta en una respuesta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3094/5481)
- [Un usuario añade una referencia de la web E_mito_logías](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3171/5481)
- [Se sugiere aceptar una respuesta, pues por desconocimiento no lo hacen](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3189/1674)
- [Un usuario deja una respuesta link-only](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4350/5481)

Answer (score 9):

#### Usuario nuevo o despistado, muchos votos negativos sin comentario explicatoria

> Por favor, no nos pasemos con los votos negativos, sobre todo con los usuarios nuevos. Animad a aprender [ask]/[answer] de acuerdo a las preferencias del sitio. Es siempre buena idea **señalar mediante comentarios lo que debe mejorarse y aportar cierta guía sobre cómo hacerlo**, animando a hacer aportaciones de calidad en lugar de simplemente penalizar. Los votos negativos pueden ser incluso contraproducentes para los intereses del sitio si no se revierten una vez el post ha sido editado y mejorado. **Es en el interés de todos nosotros que no caigamos en penalizar sin ayudar**.

Markdown:

`Por favor, no nos pasemos con los votos negativos, sobre todo con los usuarios nuevos. Animad a aprender [ask]/[answer] de acuerdo a las preferencias del sitio. Es siempre buena idea **señalar mediante comentarios lo que debe mejorarse y aportar cierta guía sobre cómo hacerlo**, animando a hacer aportaciones de calidad en lugar de simplemente penalizar. Los votos negativos pueden ser incluso contraproducentes para los intereses del sitio si no se revierten una vez el post ha sido editado y mejorado. **Es en el interés de todos nosotros que no caigamos en penalizar sin ayudar**.`

Comment: Se ve así: Por favor, no nos pasemos con los votos negativos, sobre todo con los usuarios nuevos. Animad a aprender [ask]/[answer] de acuerdo a las preferencias del sitio. Es siempre buena idea **señalar mediante comentarios lo que debe mejorarse y aportar cierta guía sobre cómo hacerlo**, animando a hacer aportaciones de calidad en lugar de simplemente penalizar. Los votos negativos pueden ser incluso contraproducentes para los intereses del sitio si no se revierten una vez el post ha sido editado y mejorado. **Es en el interés de todos nosotros que no caigamos en penalizar sin ayudar**

Answer (score 7):

#### Usuario nuevo que no contesta a lo que se pregunta:

> Bienvenido/a a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder *realmente* a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenida de nuevo. ¡Esperamos seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Markdown:

`Bienvenido/a a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder _realmente_ a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenida de nuevo. ¡Esperamos seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!`

> Welcome to [spanish.se]. We suggest you check the [tour] and [help] pages and have a look at other questions and answers to fully understand how this site works. Try your best to really answer the question, and remember that proper formatting can make your answer easier to read and understand. Keep in mind that your answer has to **explain** and not simply **direct** to another article where a proper explanation can be found. Do not hesitate to ask for help if you need it. Welcome again, and we hope to see more of your contributions!

Markdown:

`Welcome to [spanish.se]. We suggest you check the [tour] and [help] pages and have a look at other questions and answers to fully understand how this site works. Try your best to really answer the question, and remember that proper formatting can make your answer easier to read and understand. Keep in mind that your answer has to **explain** and not simply **direct** to another article where a proper explanation can be found. Do not hesitate to ask for help if you need it. Welcome again, and we hope to see more of your contributions!`

Fuente: ¡[Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16532/por-qu%C3%A9-decimos-que-estamos-empanados-cuando-tenemos-la-mente-confusa#comment31948_20825)!

Comment: Gracias. La cantidad de trabajo que me acabas de ahorrar! :-)

Comment: El comentario se ve así: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenido de nuevo. ¡Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Comment: Welcome to [spanish.se]. We suggest you to check the [tour] and [help] to fully understand how this site works. Take a look also to other questions and answers. Try your best to really answer the question and remember that proper formatting can make your answer easier to read and understand. Keep in mind that your answer has to **explain** and not simply **direct** to another article where there is a proper explanation. Do not hesitate to ask for help if you wish. Welcome again, we hope to see more of your contributions again!

Answer (score 4):

#### Una publicación es más un comentario que una respuesta.

> Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser *significativamente* distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a la respuesta aceptada. Dale al [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.

Markdown:

`Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser _significativamente_ distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a otra respuesta. Dale a [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.`

---

> Welcome to [spanish.se]! Note, the [tour] and [help] sections give a helpful introduction to the [se] approach. A well written answer focuses on exactly what's being asked, contributes something new that hasn't appeared in an answer yet, and is documented with sources, logic, or usage examples. If you have something less well developed to contribute, please use the comment box. (To do so requires a reputation of 50. If you're not there yet, never fear, that moment will come sooner than you might think.) The best way to show your agreement with an existing answer is to *upvote* it!

Markdown:

`Welcome to [spanish.se]! Note, the [tour] and [help] sections give a helpful introduction to the [se] approach. A well written answer focuses on exactly what's being asked, contributes something new that hasn't appeared in an answer yet, and is documented with sources, logic, or usage examples. If you have something less well developed to contribute, please use the comment box. (To do so requires a reputation of 50. If you're not there yet, never fear, that moment will come sooner than you might think.) The best way to show your agreement with an existing answer is to *upvote* it!`

Comment: Proposed: ¡Bienvenido a [spanish.se]! Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help], que dan una introducción a la filosofía *Stack*.  Una respuesta bien escrita responde a exactamente lo que se preguntó, aportando algo nuevo que no aparece en otra respuesta ya existente, y se documenta por medio de citas, fuentes, lógica, ejemplos, etc.  Si tienes algo breve que decir, deja un comentario, por favor.  (Esto requiere reputación de 15, pero verás qué rápido se llega a ese nivel.)  ¡Fíjate que si quieres mostrar que estás de acuerdo con una respuesta, lo mejor es votar a favor!

Comment: In English: Welcome to [spanish.se]! Note, the [tour] and [help] sections give a helpful introduction to the [se] approach. A well written answer focuses on exactly what's being asked, contributes something new that hasn't appeared in an answer yet, and is documented with sources, logic, or usage examples. If you have something less well developed to contribute, please use the comment box. (To do so requires a reputation of 50. If you're not there yet, never fear, that moment will come sooner than you might think.) The best way to show your agreement with an existing answer is to *upvote* it!

Answer (score 4):

#### Usuario nuevo que no pregunta correctamente (cambiar XXX por el motivo que sea):

> ¡Bienvenido a [spanish.SE]! La pregunta parece interesante, pero tal y como está redactada lo más probable es que se cierre debido a que XXX. Te animamos a que la [edit]es y mejores añadiendo la información que falta. Puedes consultar la documentación sobre cómo hacer buenas preguntas en [ask]. También puedes darte una vuelta por el [tour] para más información sobre la filosofía del sitio. Bienvenido de nuevo, ¡esperamos más contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Posibles causas de XXX:

- ... tal y como está no queda claro qué es lo que preguntas exactamente.
- ... deberías comentarnos qué has investigado hasta ahora, para que podamos entender exactamente cuál es tu duda.

Markdown:

`Hola, lo que explicas en esta respuesta ya estaba bastante presente en otras respuestas anteriores. Date cuenta de que si lo que quieres es respaldar cierto contenido puedes votar esa respuesta. Si quieres ampliar ¿podrías proporcionar algún tipo de explicación o motivos de uso que mejoren la comprensión? Suele ayudar decir qué forma se usa en tu zona, dar elementos históricos que lo expliquen, etc. Más info en [answer].`

> Hello and welcome to [spanish.se], and thank you for contributing a question!  Unfortunately, in its current form, your question may get closed, as it lacks an explanation of what research you've done so far, where you got stuck, how the word you're seeking would be used in a sentence, etc. See [ask] and [tour].  Could you [edit] the post to make your question clearer, so we can assist you?

Markdown:

`Hello and welcome to [spanish.se], and thank you for contributing a question!  Unfortunately, in its current form, your question may get closed, as it lacks an explanation of what research you've done so far, where you got stuck, how the word you're seeking would be used in a sentence, etc. See [ask] and [tour].  Could you [edit] the post to make your question clearer, so we can assist you?`

Comment: What it looks like: ¡Bienvenido a [spanish.SE]! La pregunta parece interesante, pero tal y como está redactada lo más probable es que se cierre debido a que XXX. Te animamos a que la [edit]es y mejores añadiendo la información que falta. Puedes consultar la documentación sobre cómo hacer buenas preguntas en [ask]. También puedes darte una vuelta por el [tour] para más información sobre la filosofía del sitio. Bienvenido de nuevo, ¡esperamos más contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Comment: Hello and welcome to [spanish.se], and thank you for contributing a question!  Unfortunately, in its current form, your question may get closed, as it lacks an explanation of what research you've done so far, where you got stuck, how the word you're seeking would be used in a sentence, etc. See [ask] and [tour].  Could you [edit] the post to make your question clearer, so we can assist you?

Answer (score 3):

#### Un post es *demasiado* parecido a uno ya existente.

> ¡Hola! Tu respuesta es similar a otras respuestas anteriores. Si estás de acuerdo con lo que dicen y quieres mostrar tu apoyo, lo mejor es votar esas respuestas y/o dejar un comentario, para evitar tener muchas respuestas iguales. Si lo que quieres es ampliar o mejorar la información o dar otro enfoque, considera [edit]ar tu respuesta para añadir una explicación, decir de qué forma se usa en tu zona, aportar elementos históricos, etc. Más info en [answer].

Markdown:

`¡Hola! Tu respuesta es similar a otras respuestas anteriores. Si estás de acuerdo con lo que dicen y quieres mostrar tu apoyo, lo mejor es votar esas respuestas y/o dejar un comentario, para evitar tener muchas respuestas iguales. Si lo que quieres es ampliar o mejorar la información o dar otro enfoque, considera [edit]ar tu respuesta para añadir una explicación, decir de qué forma se usa en tu zona, aportar elementos históricos, etc. Más info en [answer].`

---

> Hi! Your answer is quite similar to some of the existing answers.  I'd suggest you expand your answer (by clicking on [edit]), or put your text in the comment box instead.  To expand your answer, consider providing an explanation, usage examples in your region, historical background, etc.  If you don't have enough reputation yet to write a comment, be patient, that moment will come sooner than you might think....  Meanwhile, the best way to show support for an existing answer is to upvote it!  For more information, see [answer].

Markdown:

`Hi! Your answer is quite similar to some of the existing answers.  I'd suggest you expand your answer (by clicking on [edit]), or put your text in the comment box instead.  To expand your answer, consider providing an explanation, usage examples in your region, historical background, etc.  If you don't have enough reputation yet to write a comment, be patient, that moment will come sooner than you might think....  Meanwhile, the best way to show support for an existing answer is to upvote it!  For more information, see [answer].`

Answer (score 3):

Un usuario añade un enlace a la web de [Emitologías](https://emitologias.wordpress.com/2015/09/01/emitologias-s02e01/) como referencia sobre el origen de una expresión.

Últimamente estoy viendo muchos caso de estos y he decidido crearme aquí una buena plantilla para dejar un comentario advirtiendo al usuario de que la web **inventa** las etimologías y orígenes de expresiones. Dado que la web no es nada clara al respecto y que mucho usuarios, especialmente los más nuevos, se suelen molestar cuando se les critica por este hecho, he conseguido encontrar un post de la propia web de Emitologías donde el autor confirma que se inventa los orígenes.

Así es como queda el comentario (599 caracteres ya, así que no hay donde añadir nada)

> E*mito*logías ("Explicaciones *mitológicas* para expresiones cotidianas") es una web de humor que **inventa** orígenes coloridos y humorísticos ("mitológicos") sobre las expresiones. El propio autor lo confirma en [esta entrada](https://emitologias.wordpress.com/2015/09/01/emitologias-s02e01/). La falta de claridad al respecto (que le ha ganado muchas críticas), junto a la falta de meticulosidad de otros al comprobar fuentes, ha llevado a mucha confusión e incorrecciones refiriendo al contenido de la web. Por esta razón, *esta web no es una fuente fiable sobre el origen de ninguna expresión*.

Markdown (lo que puedes coger para el copia-pega)

`E*mito*logías ("Explicaciones *mitológicas* para expresiones cotidianas") es una web de humor que **inventa** orígenes coloridos y humorísticos ("mitológicos") sobre las expresiones. El propio autor lo confirma en [esta entrada](https://emitologias.wordpress.com/2015/09/01/emitologias-s02e01/). La falta de claridad al respecto (que le ha ganado muchas críticas), junto a la falta de meticulosidad de otros al comprobar fuentes, ha llevado a mucha confusión e incorrecciones refiriendo al contenido de la web. Por esta razón, *esta web no es una fuente fiable sobre el origen de ninguna expresión*.`

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia. Se me ha pasado pedir un "translation-golf", para ver si esto podía ser más corte. La verdad es que la negrita me gusta más que la cursiva. Luego lo cambio.

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta de un usuario nuevo, que aporta una hipótesis nueva sin aportar referencias:

> Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!

Markdown:

`Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!`

Answer (score 2):

Para ususarios que dejan una respuesta que es apenas un enlace:

> We tend to discourage "link only" answers. Nothing is explained in the contribution and users need to visit some other (random) site and figure out by themselves what the relevant content is or try to understand it on their own. If the linked page goes missing, this post loses all value. Instead, please bring here the relevant content of the cited link and **explain** in your own words how that answers the question. Leave the link as reference and/or as a "further reading" or useful resource, but avoid answers that instead of explaining content just send you somewhere else for your answer.

O esta otra enlatada:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

## Vanilla introduction for new users

Welcome to [spanish.se]! Note, the [tour] and [help] sections give a helpful introduction to the [se] approach. A well written answer focuses on exactly what's being asked, contributes something new that hasn't appeared in an answer yet, and is documented with sources, logic, or usage examples. If you have something less well developed to contribute, please use the comment box. (To do so requires a reputation of 50. If you're not there yet, never fear, that moment will come sooner than you might think.) The best way to show your agreement with an existing answer is to *upvote* it!

Answer (score 1):

#### Un usuario plantea una nueva pregunta en una respuesta

Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Si tienes una pregunta propia, [plantéala como tal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenido de nuevo. ¡Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Markdown:

`Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Si tienes una pregunta propia, [plantéala como tal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenido de nuevo. ¡Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!`

Answer (score 1):

#### Se sugiere aceptar una respuesta, pues por desconocimiento no lo hacen

> ¿Solucionó tu problema, @usuario? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Markdown:

`¿Solucionó tu problema, @usuario? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!`