# Usuario sin registrar (con 1 punto de reputación) hizo comentario en mi pregunta

Tags: soporte, comentarios, privilegios

En el siguiente [enlace](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-la-expresi%C3%B3n-paquete-chileno#comment33934_15847) podrán ver el comentario de un usuario que, según su perfil, está sin registrar.

*Este es el comentario del nuevo usuario:*
[image: Comentario del usuario nuevo]

Tenía entendido que solo con [puntuación de 50](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) se puede generar comentarios en las preguntas y repuestas de otros usuarios.

¿Esta situación acaso fue un error?

---

Solo para aclarar, no estoy presentando alguna queja sobre el contenido del comentario, sino que me resulta curioso que un usuario nuevo "sin registrar" haya hecho un comentario en mi pregunta - sin tener aún el privilegio concedido según su reputación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este usuario respondió originalmente a la pregunta con un post-respuesta (con exactamente ese mismo contenido), no con un comentario. Es cierto que no habría tenido suficiente reputación para comentar.

Revisando las contribuciones nuevas vi esta respuesta y evalué que su contenido es un comentario, no una respuesta, ya que no responde (ni siquiera lo intenta) a la pregunta original: **¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "paquete chileno"?**

Por eso, **haciendo uso de las herramientas de moderador migré su respuesta a comentario**. Con reputación suficiente (2000) [se pueden ver los post eliminados](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), en cuyo caso podrías ver algo como la siguiente imagen

[image]

Normalmente [dejamos una serie de comentarios](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2622/5481) a los usuarios nuevos, a aquellos que no responden realmente a la preguntas planteadas o a aquellos cuyas contribuciones son de muy baja calidad, para animarles a mejorar sus contribuciones, mostrarles links de referencia útiles (como las secciones, [tour](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tour), [How to ask](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [how to answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) o el [centro de ayuda](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help)) y para dar la bienvenida, ofrecer ayuda, etc.

En el caso de este usuario, dado que

- Es un usuario no registrado, como bien indicas
- No muestra ningún interés en responder a la pregunta original
- Hace referencia a "Pinocho" (entiendo que por Pinochet), dando un tono "*jocoso*" en el mejor de los casos, y el contenido de su contribución es claramente un "comentario rápido" aclaratorio

no me molesté en dejar el comentario de "bienvenida + por-favor-mejora-tu-post" asumiendo que este usuario nunca va a volver para mejorar esa contribución (si lo hiciese podría *editar* su respuesta y luego levantar un flag para que un moderador hiciese un *undelete*).

Al migrar un post de respuesta a comentario se pueden migrar también como comentarios (o no) cualesquiera comentarios que ese post respuesta tenga asociados, a opción del moderador realizando la tarea de "limpieza". Los comentarios también se pueden migrar a chat.

No es raro que usuarios que no saben cómo funciona la filosofía de los stacks posteen como respuestas cosas que debieran ser comentarios (por desconocimiento o porque por falta de reputación suficiente para comentar deciden *abusar* el sistema publicando un post-respuesta).

**Todos los usuarios está invitados a participar en las tareas de moderación**. Con reputación suficiente se accede además a [las colas de revisión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues). La funcionalidad para migrar posts solo está disponible a moderadores.

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21648/5481) es otro ejemplo de un usuario que abusa del sistema. Como ves, varios usuarios han levantado un _flag_ para indicar que esta contribución no responde realmente a la pregunta, aunque fue publicada como respuesta. Hemos dejado un mensaje apuntando a los enlaces pertinentes y ofreciendo ayuda. Si en un tiempo prudencial el usuario no modifica esa contribución, pues habrá que migrarla también a comentario.

Comment: Gracias Diego, y, yo editaría esta parte en negrilla: *haciendo uso de las herramientas de moderador migré su comentario a respuesta.* - para futuros lectores. Saludos.