# ¿Se puede hacer algo con los comentarios abusivos, más allá de "banderearlos"?

Tags: discusión, usuario-community

Había leído en *Medium* que Stack Exchange tiene cierta fama de ser una comunidad relativamente difícil para los usuarios nuevos de integrarse, y en cierta manera, los sitios más técnicos donde usualmente la respuesta correcta tiene poco margen de interpretación, podrían dar esa impresión (SO, SuperUser, ServerFault).

Pero me sorprende tristemente ver preguntas [como esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25857/el-g%C3%A9nero-de-los-adjectivos-con-agua) que a más de tener 4 usuarios de alta reputación *burlándose* de la pregunta (porque es tan obvia la respuesta para un angloparlante también).

> ¿Qué procede en estos casos, o qué puede hacer uno mas allá de
>   "banderear" los comentarios abusivos y no conducentes a una discusión
>   sana?

El daño probablemente ya esté hecho, hay un usuario que seguramente no tendrá deseos de ventilar sus dudas sobre el castellano aquí, y seguro junto con él algunos miembros de su cohorte, pues nadie aprende lenguajes por sí solo hoy en día...

Comment: En un principio pensé, ¿Qué hay aquí, por qué no veo no grosero que encontró hlecuanda, y luego pensé, ay caramba, pues lo grosero ya se habrá quitado por las banderas!

Comment: De hecho. Es un mecanismo muy eficaz. Cualquiera puede ser moderador dentro de lo que permita tus privilegios lo que evita la formaciones de "Clicas" tóxicas. Hay mucha psicología y experiencia en comunidades en línea detrás del sistema SE. Y finciona relativamente bien.

Comment: En esta pregunta en específico no veo las burlas ¿borraron algún comentario? Si es por el mío, efectivamente estaba indicando que esta pregunta podría formar parte de las preguntas canónicas, no era una ironía.

Comment: Es correcto, después de colocar las banderas y hacer voz de mi desacuerdo, los comentarios aludidos desaparecieron poco tiempo después. Primero supuse que habría sido efecto de la banderita, aunque más bien pudo haber sido acccion del mismo usuario o de algún moderador. Me pareció excesivo hacer un screenshot de la página, pero las respuestas eran al estilo de un *reductio ad absurdum* de la pregunta y otros comentarios solo tenían carcajadas onomatopeyicas con la respectiva referencia al @usuario que hizo el primera arguiblemente jocoso comentario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razón tienes, pero con un par de "peros".

Principalmente, el ego es un problema en muchos sitios, y en internet no se ponen las cosas más fáciles, precisamente porque el anonimato de los usuarios y la distancia que pone el medio hace que la gente se envalentone y diga cosas a otros que jamás diría a la cara (sin necesidad de temer un ataque físico). Hay gente que para destacar (e inflar su ego) tiene que rebajar a otros.

Yo creo que Spanish.se sí es en general un stack mucho más amable que algunos de sus stacks "primos". A la lista que propones yo añadiría el stack de Sci.Fi. No entiendo cómo en un stack en que se dedican a preguntar sobre Harry Potter y porqué no se le rompen los pantalones al increíble Hulk cuando se transforma lleguen a ser tan abusivos a veces con la gente que anda un poco despistada.

Yo creo que aquí sí que hemos invertido bastante esfuerzo en concienciar a la comunidad (que creo que ya es maja y con ganas de ayudar de por sí) de no ser demasiado ariscos con la gente que anda perdida por ser nuevos. Mira la "[Lista de comentarios útiles para el sitio](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2622/5481)" .

Sobre el caso particular que apuntas u otros parecidos, un par de cosas:

1. Asume buena fe. Internet no es un medio fácil para transmitir ciertas cosas (El investigador Albert Mehrabian descompuso en porcentajes el impacto de un mensaje: 7% es verbal, 38% vocal (tono, matices y otras características) y un 55% señales y gestos. Los emoticonos son pobres sustitutos de la comunicación no verbal). Quizá en algunos comentarios la gente no transmite bien que se están riendo **con** alguien en lugar de **de** alguien. Y por la falta de cuidado de uno al redactar y por un malentendido de la otra parte, pues parece lo que no es.
2. No dudes en llamar la atención de los moderadores sobre algo así, para que lo investiguemos. También puedes poner tu propio comentario para dejar que aquél usuario que piensas que está insultando, se explique un poco más. Te recomiendo encarecidamente si haces esto que dejes que la gente "salve la cara", y en lugar de llegar y señalar con el dedo o arrinconarlos de forma agresiva por groseros dejes caer graciosamente un "Pon un emoticono para que se sepa que es broma" o algo similar.

Comment: Excelente consejos sobre todo los que apuntas al final sobre cómo manejar una incidencia. Efectivamente este stack es bastante amigable por eso me sorprendió tanto la situacion. Tal vez pude hacer hecho mejor el que los involucrados tengan oportunidad de "salvar rostro" pero hice muy clara mi objeción a lo que se estaba desarrollando. Por otro lado, esrioy familiarizado con los efectos del anonimato en comunidades en línea. La estructura de SO mitiga exitosamebre las tendencias negativas con el hecho de asociar una identidad en la que se debe invertir (rep) para participar.