# Newcomer's off-topic post: to downvote or not to downvote?

Tags: discusión, off-topic, votos-negativos, nuevos-usuarios

How this question originated: I read an [interesting discussion in La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45107274#45107274) about whether it's a good idea to downvote a newcomer's off-topic question.  I thought this could be a fruitful discussion in Meta, something for us to figure out as a community as we work our way towards graduation.

Here's the [question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45107274#45107274) that sparked the discussion:

> En Colombia es común decir “¡Cómo eres de vanidosa!” o “¡Cómo eres de vanidoso!” de manera positiva, como diciendo: “Te cuidas, te gusta verte bien y estar bien presentado/a”.  En inglés le dije a alguien “You are so vain” y se sintió insultado. ¿Cómo le explico cuál es la palabra equivalente en inglés para que entienda que no buscaba insultarlo?

Do you think closing it is enough behavior shaping, or do you think one or more downvotes are a helpful disincentive?

Comment: I cannot understand these posts, aparente. I think it is useful to open debates, but at the same time of doing so, you directly post your wannabe-canonical answers. This is not a debate, then, it is just an excuse to express your views. Also, this appears to be a generic post, while you are talking about specific questions and answers. So either talk generically or talk about a specific post, but do not mix things.

Comment: @fedorqui - What is a better format for requesting others' views, and contributing my own?  Look, I saw, on Tertulia (an open page that anyone can read) an interesting discussion of a specific response to a specific question.  I wanted to participate.  I wanted to invite others to participate.  I thought it was of enough general interest, and substantial enough, for it to be moved to Meta.  If you have a better way of doing that, I hope you will do so.  The two-person debate I saw you having in Tertulia was interesting and, in my opinion, worth inviting others to participate in.

Comment: I did some reading about criteria for graduation of Beta sites.  It's my understanding that Beta sites can't get promoted to full sites without a thriving Meta where the nitty gritty of community moderation gets hashed out.

Comment: Both sides in the two-person debate I read were reasonable.  The debate itself seemed positive, respectful, productive.  But a bit hidden away.  Why not open it up to additional participation?

Comment: _Hey, I read user A defends this and user B defends that in La Tertulia. I think X, what do you guys think about it?_

Comment: @fedorqui - That seems like an accurate boiling down of my question.  Thank you.

Comment: Aparente001 I'm sorry, but I still cant help feeling that **you are all over the place**. Following our discussion in my answer, you edited your question to stress focus on off-topic questions and their answers from newcomers. Yet, one of your posts ("regarding answers") illustrates your case with an answer to a question that, AFAIK, has never been flagged as offtopic (but as both lowQuality and NotAnAnswer). Your edits to your question have some "backwards compatibility" problem with the answer you provided in the first place, which makes me think you dont really know what you want to discuss

Comment: @aparente001 no. What I said is what I propose for a productive debate. Instead, this was something like _Hey, I read people talking about X; no matter what they said, let me ask about it generically and also provide my point of views in answers, so this seems to be the cannonical point of view_. Note how the approaches differ: if you doubt about something, you ask and wait for people to answer. We are a community with everybody in the same level, there is no need to _teach_ users.

Comment: If you want to stimulate the debate, express your views in questions. Then we will answer. Otherwise, it is quite hard to get something productive out of it, specially if you keep editing the posts and make them so different.

Comment: Hmm.  I made a bit of a mess.  (The example I used in my "regarding answers"  post actually had nothing to do, strictly speaking, with off-topic questions.)  I'm going to try to clean this up.  My plan is to remove the "regarding answers" post and move that material to a new question, and rewrite the material here on this page.  Give me a little while to work it all out.  Once I've got it set I'll post a new comment.  If it still needs work please let me know.

Comment: @aparente001 What if instead of creating multiple meta questions for a really similar issue you just focus your question on "a newcomers' bad post"? What is the value of having multiple discussion for offtopic questions, on-topic low quality questions, including (or not) their answers, low quality and "not an answer" answers to other questions, etc. Does it really matter the type of contribution (so much as to discuss it and handle it separately) when deciding when to downvote (and what to do) with a newcomer _bad_ contribution? I would actually post my same answer on any of those meta posts.

Comment: @aparente001 Also, please read carefully fedorqui's advice. You should not be using Meta as if it was your personal twitter account or blog (to just tell the world your thoughts on something). It should be a place where you ask a question to invite the opinions of others to figure out a problem. You are using it too much just to give visibility to your own opinions. You tend to post a question, almost as an excuse to write your own answer to your own question. These contributions are having lower than usual participation rate, because they actually don't seem to invite to productive discussion

Comment: @Diego - I am in the midst of moving house and was not able to finalize this morning's edits until now.  Apologies. // Thanks again to you and everyone who provided the helpful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

#### Closing is enough

Downvoting is unnecessary in situations where the author has shown clear effort.

OP didn't realize that this type of question is off topic here but on topic at ELL or ELU.  Clearly it needed to be closed -- I'm sure we're all on the same page about that -- but in other respects it was a pretty well written question, I thought.

It can be discouraging and off-putting for a newcomer to be downvoted right off the bat, and in this case I especially don't see a need to downvote.  The OP went to the effort of explaining what was being asked, and I think this effort should be acknowledged by refraining from downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,

> In what circumstances should we downvote a newcomer's "bad" post?

In whichever circumstances that we, as individuals, see fit depending on number of (probably subjective) variables, mainly, but not limited to:

- How useful that particular post is (what value does it bring to the site)
- How clearly information is presented (including formatting, punctuation and making the ideas easy to understand an digest)
- Amount of effort appreciated in the post

My understanding is that there are some aspects of the site governance and some policies that we cannot and should not enforce.

We award reputation, and thus privileges, as a way of **empowering** users who demonstrated, through their continuous worthwhile contributions, competence in creating the kind of value that we strive forth, so they do more (and greater and better) of the same. It would be a contradiction not to trust these users' best judgement.

I'm a firm believer of leading through the example. My go-to solution is using the [Lista de comentarios útiles para el sitio](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2622/5481) and leave a polite, understanding, non-accusatory and non-admonishing comment that I might need to revisit in the near future to see if the poster understood and followed through (quite some effort). Other times, specially for low quality answers, I'm less prone to be lenient with poorly redacted content that does not address the question and comes from an unregistered user.

I use downvotes (and "low quality" and "not an answer" flags) at my own discretion and I'm aware that a downvote is unlikely to bring any change by itself unless the OP understands why part of their contribution doesn't meet my standards (not *the site's standards*, but **my** standards for what we should strive for. Important distinction here. I might downvote something and the OP might disagree with my criteria, and decide that their post is *not* going to change to adjust to my criteria).

Overall, I feel that this is a "problem" that we revisit often. Still,

- I don't think that this site is unfriendly to new users, or that they are not given plenty of help with their very first contributions
- I don't think that posts of new users get heavily downvoted when exhibiting "low-qualityness"
- I don't see entitled users (neither towards newcomers or other users)
- I don't think that a "new users *can't* be downvoted" policy is the way to go either. If we are to teach the philosophy of the stack, that means inculcating both aiming to write quality contributions as well as accepting criticism.
- When exercising the privilege to downvote conflicts the ["be nice"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy, we have plenty of mechanisms to manage this, without needing to enforce a "don't downvote newcomers so they don't get sad" policy

### To summarize:

I think that we revisit this kind of interaction so often because **we are trying to micromanage it**, and we shouldn't. I think that diversity of opinion and trust on those who earned the downvote privilege should prevail. Users will be more or less permissive depending on many different aspects of the post (or even the stack as a whole).

It is worth asking ourselves before downvoting: "what I am trying to get with this downvote? How am I helping to make this post - and the content of the stack- better?" and remember that, **if we strive for quality content, is to help people**, and that the way we teach users and new users also has an influence in the way they perceive what we teach them and in the way we are motivating them to be better.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to the discussion I opened! // I didn't understand all of this, but there were some parts that I *think* I understood, which showed me that some of what I wrote was misunderstood.  I'd like to clear up the misunderstandings.  I will do that as an update to one of my posts -- I'm thinking maybe the answer that focuses on voting about off-topic questions would be the best place.

Comment: @aparente001 Comments are supposed to be used for clarification (to request or give). If you tell me which parts you didn't understand I can try to clarify. Also, I dont understand the rush to edit your posts based on what you think mine says. Mine is my opinion, and I didnt write it to answer your answers or anything like that. I wrote my opinion about downvoting new users' "bad" (for whichever reason) posts (which tangentially touched downvoting in general). I didn't think that there was a reason why I should only focus on off-topic questions when thinking about this.

Comment: *"I didn't think that there was a reason why I should only focus on off-topic questions when thinking about this."* Thanks for explaining. I was confused because I tried to make it clear in the title and body of the question that my focus here was specifically about off-topic questions.  In other words, I was imagining a flow chart, with the first diamond at the top of the page saying "Is the question off topic?" and the Yes branch being the sole focus of this Meta question.

Comment: I'm fine with listing the things I didn't understand if you really want me to.  (I won't do that right away in case you want to first narrow your focus to off-topic questions, which is what I'm hoping will be the focus here.) // Why did I go ahead and post a response last night?  I felt I understood most of the bulleted section pretty well, and I was concerned about possible misunderstandings of my views. In other words, I wanted to clarify my views right away so others wouldn't misread them based on your post.

Comment: @aparente001 You posted two answers to your own question. One focuses on answers ("Regarding answers") and the other on questions. Yet, you just claimed "I tried to make it clear in the title and body of the question that **my focus here was specifically about off-topic questions**". What?? Did you then write an answer to something you knew you were **not** asking on your own question? Why? It feels to me that you are all over the place. Meta is not your soapbox or pulpit. Think about what you want the community to discuss, not about what you want to tell to the community or instruct them with

Comment: @aparente001 I won't  narrow my focus to off-topic questions. I believe that the interesting discussion here is *how to handle newcomers' low quality contributions* (how do we teach them, how much should we shield them from criticism/downvoting, if downvoting is counterproductive in this cases, tools/mechanism to deal with this problem...). If we focus only on offtopic questions, are we going to create a number of other meta posts like this for low quality answers, answers that are not answers and low quality questions of newcomers? Or handle them differently? I don't see a reason to do that.

Comment: If you prefer, the title can be changed and the material rearranged.  I am hoping to bring the importance of supporting newcomers to the fore.  Newcomers often make mistakes.  I'd like to see our site supporting them in a more consistently positive way.  It's frustrating to see the *way* I brought this up being focused on so much.  Just move things around, please, if the arrangement of my material is so off base.  My hope is that the ideas I was writing about can take center stage.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm *not* focusing on the way you brought this up I already explained why I think **we should discuss both types of posts**. You commented on my answer that the focus should be only questions (and invited me to "narrow it" accordingly), because (you said) is what you specified on your question. Yet, the body of your question says "There are newcomer questions, and there are newcomer answers. **On this page I propose that we discuss both types of posts**" and you yourself posted an answer about answers. Yet, you tell me to focus just on questions, so I pointed out the contradiction

Comment: Thanks that helped me see what was not clear about my question.  I've edited it to make it clearer.  I hope this clears up the intention of the question.