# Moderator election: interest check

Tags: discusión, elecciones, moderadores

The Community team is considering running a graduation election on our site. A graduation election would have three moderator positions available, and current moderators would need to nominate themselves and win in order to keep their diamond. The election would not increase the total number of moderators: it might just replace some of the current ones. The graduation election also would not automatically imply other changes related to graduation. In particular, there are no plans to change the privilege levels in the near future.

The main advantage of a successful election would be to legitimate the (new) set of moderators, because last time we were [appointed without a vote](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4397/24236) and we may not represent what the community wants.

A graduation election can only run if there are enough candidates for it to be competitive (i.e., **four** candidates).

This post is an interest check to see if we would reach the required number of candidates if we were to hold an election.

For the moment, the workload of moderating Spanish Language Stack Exchange is not high, as the site gets about 1-2 moderator flags a day. I am available to answer any questions about moderation: feel free to ask in comments or to ping me in chat.

If you would be willing to volunteer as a moderator, please post an answer here or let us know in some other way. If it looks like we could have a competitive election, we will inform the Community team and hopefully have a graduation election soon.

As for me, I would nominate myself if there were an election.

Comment: Maybe this question should elaborate on the benefits of (or the rationale for) the Graduation election, and also if the 3 current mods are running for reelection. Do we need just 1 candidate or up to 4? In any case, I'll repeat what I said after [the previous election](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4399/5481) and about [lowering the close/reopen thresholds](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3272/5481)(see comments): we seem to be voluntarily blind to the problems of the stack and we just treat symptoms or deal with unimportant stuff. Due to that we have lost our community.

Comment: I agree with @Diego. I do not see what benefits the site would gain from having more moderators or from graduating. We continue with a low level of participation, from time to time we lose substantial contributors, and reviewing is the province of a select few of us.

Comment: @Diego I edited the question: an election gives a chance to legitimate the set of moderators, it won't automatically cause other changes related to graduation, and I would nominate myself. As for the problem of low engagement/participation, I honestly do not know how to solve it. I nominate myself mostly to prevent a total shutdown.

Comment: @mdewey see my previous comment and the edited question.

Comment: Sorry, but what is a "graduation election"? I have never heard that in my life and it is not usual in English. Also, please: we say legitimize something. Wimi, I posted a message to you in the Chat Room and you didn't even answer. So....I dunno.

Comment: @Lambie ["'Graduation' Election"](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/605/announcing-a-graduation-election-for-2021) is a stack exchange term. [*legitimate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/legitimate#Verb) is perfectly fine to use as a verb. It's not very nice making condescending remarks about people's grammar/word choice.

Comment: @jacobo I would have to say that in the dialect I hear around me _legitimate_ as a verb does rather jar but obviously your mileage varies.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts @wimi. Thanks for editing. It's interesting that you mention the "total shutdown". I think CMs scared people w/ that during the latest election, got their mods appointed & departed with their job done but leaving a *leaderless community* to deal with its own problems. I hold them accountable for their ill advice and neglect of this stack. They're in part responsible for the current condition of the site, since they pushed the community to avoid the "total shutdown threat" and the trade-off is this "perpetual apathy" in which few would care if this stack was shut down.

Comment: Coincido y siento en carne propia la apatía generalizada que destaca @Diego. También opino que [el anterior intento de elecciones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4397/1674) dejó un regusto bastante desagradable, en el que parece que prevaleció la necesidad de asignar a alguien y dar el sitio por "resuelto" en lugar de generar complicidades para fortalecerlo. Yo le tengo mucho cariño al sitio pero cada vez creo que difiere más el objetivo de la empresa con los que teníamos cuando entrábamos aquí y lo convertimos en un lugar bastante potente y vibrante.