# ¿Desde cuándo le damos un -3 a un nuevo usuario que simplemente no conoce la diferencia entre comentario y respuesta?

Tags: discusión, votos, nuevos-usuarios

Jamás he visto tantos votos negativos en una situación así, en este sitio.  Habría que tratar a los nuevos usuarios con más compasión, a mi aviso.

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32702/9385

No era spam, y no era nocivo su post.

Espero que alguien retracte su voto negativo, porque si no, el autor ni siquiera podrá ver mi comentario, donde explico que es mejor dejar un comentario cuando no se aporta algo significativo, y donde le doy la bienvenida al sitio.

Comment: Nótese por cierto que votar positivo porque otros han votado negativos no tiene razón de ser. Debemos votar por contenido. Los comentarios lo habría visto el usuario a menos que se le hubiera votado la publicación.

Comment: @fedorqui - No sabía que los votos negativos se habían dado por la máquina.  Además, me parecía que el post no carecía de valor.  Ahora que tiene voto neto de +5, parece que otras cuatro personas le encontraron valor también.

Comment: sí, entiendo la confusión: ¡sienta mal ver algo moderadamente decente con tal cantidad de votos negativos!

Comment: Algunos de los [comentarios enlatados](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2622/5481) que tenemos están pensado para estos casos, particularmente  [Usuario nuevo o despistado, muchos votos negativos sin comentario explicatoria](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2624/5481), resumiendo en una frase: "**Es en el interés de todos nosotros que no caigamos en penalizar sin ayudar.**" A veces estos comentarios ayudan a romper la inercia de "Lo veo en alguna de las colas de revisión con _downvotes_ y le doy yo uno también sin ni siquiera mirarlo o comentar"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El post contenía un enlace a un sitio de *streaming* ilegal de películas, por lo que el [SmokeDetector](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259363/209901) alertó de la publicación, lo que hizo que recibiera varios flags por *spam* de gente que está revisando las notificaciones de este bot<sup>1</sup>, lo que le acarreó los negativos<sup>2</sup>.

He resuelto los flags indicando que la publicación es válida y que el enlace ha sido eliminado. Lo que habría que hacer es alertar al usuario de que no vuelva a añadir enlaces a sitios de *streaming* ilegales.

---

1 <sub>En la sala [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) se publican todas las notificaciones y en [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia) las de Spanish.SE.</sub>

2 <sub>Cada reporte por spam acarrea un voto negativo automático por parte del usuario Community, según [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/209901).</sub>

Comment: Igual ni sabía que era ilegal... eso de la legalidad depende del país y a saber donde andamos cada uno

Comment: @IriaPoncelaBlanco no es porque fuera ilegal, es porque el SmokeDetector lo marcó como posible spam, y como este sistema alerta de los posts sospechosos, algunos usuarios lo marcaron como spam directamente sin comprobarlo y de ahí los votos negativos. Una vez que se comprobó que el post era correcto los votos negativos se eliminaron, y de hecho ahora mismo el post es de los más votados.